# Blank space at the right of the div which has width:100% property

Tags: html, css

There is a blank space at the right of the div which I use as a topbar. I want it to cover the page horizontally 100%, but that small space at the right of the page seems to go anywhere.

I tried adding `padding:0;` and `margin:0;` to the body property but it didn't work.

[image: Image of space]

There are no other CSS at play since I've been re-designing the page.

```css
body {

    background-image:url(images/background-awcc.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;

}

/* Top Menu All Pages */

.topmenu {

    padding:30px;
    background-color:rgba(55, 21, 21, 1);
    border-right:solid rgba(55, 21, 21, 1);
    margin-left:-9px;
    margin-top:-9px;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing : border-box;
}

.topmenulink {

    padding:30px;
    color:antiquewhite;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.topmenulink:visited  {

    text-decoration:none;
    color:burlywood;

}

.topmenulink:hover  {

    background-color:darkgoldenrod;
    color:black;

}
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="topmenu">

            <a class="topmenulink" href="myaccount.php">My Account</a>
            <a class="topmenulink" href="appointments.php">Appointments</a>
            <a class="topmenulink" href="tutors.php">Tutors</a>
            <a class="topmenulink" href="clients.php">Clients</a>
            <a class="topmenulink" href="schedule.php">Schedule</a>
            <a class="topmenulink" href="statistics.php">Statistics</a>
            <a class="topmenulink" href="help.php">Help</a>
            <a class="topmenulink" href="logout.php">Logout</a>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try settgin html, body width to 100% and margin padding 0

Comment: Why do you have `margin-left:-9px;`?  That will affect your layout.

Comment: @JosephMarikle yeah I just realized lol, I was re-designing as I said. I feel stupid. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove margin-left -9px from the topmenu classname

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `margin-left: -9px` from `.topmenu` seems to alleviate your issue.

```css
body {

    background-image:url(images/background-awcc.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;

}

/* Top Menu All Pages */

.topmenu {

    padding:30px;
    background-color:rgba(55, 21, 21, 1);
    border-right:solid rgba(55, 21, 21, 1);
    margin-top:-9px;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing : border-box;
}

.topmenulink {

    padding:30px;
    color:antiquewhite;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.topmenulink:visited  {
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
        <div class="topmenu">

            <a class="topmenulink" href="myaccount.php">My Account</a>
            <a class="topmenulink" href="appointments.php">Appointments</a>
            <a class="topmenulink" href="tutors.php">Tutors</a>
            <a class="topmenulink" href="clients.php">Clients</a>
            <a class="topmenulink" href="schedule.php">Schedule</a>
            <a class="topmenulink" href="statistics.php">Statistics</a>
            <a class="topmenulink" href="help.php">Help</a>
            <a class="topmenulink" href="logout.php">Logout</a>

        </div>
    </div>
```